# Java parsing html elements generated by JS

Tags: java, parsing, web-scraping, html-parsing, jsoup

I'm very new to html parsing with Java, I used JSoup previously to parse simple html without it dynamically changing, however I now need to parse a web page that has dynamic elements. This is the code I attempted to parse the web page with prior however it was impossible to find the elements since they where added after the page had loaded. The situation is question is a page that uses google maps with markers on it, I'm attempting to scrape the images of these markers.

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
try {
    doc = Jsoup.connect("https://pokevision.com")
            .userAgent(
                    "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/51.0.2704.106 Safari/537.36")
            .get();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
Elements images = doc.select("img[src~=(?i)\\.(png|jpe?g|gif)]");

for (Element image : images) {
    System.out.println("src : " + image.attr("src"));
}

}
```

So since apparently this operation is impossible with JSoup, what other libraries can I use to find the image sources. [image: Example of an element I am attempting to select]

Comment: please see [You cannot Parse HTML with Regex](/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

Comment: @Tibrogargan that is a css selector which is supported by Jsoup: https://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/selector-syntax

Answer (score 1):

The problem you are facing is [Jsoup](https://jsoup.org/) retrieves the static source code, as it would be delivered to a browser.  What you want is the DOM after the javaScript has been invoked.  For this, you can use [HTML Unit](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/) to get the rendered page and then pass its content to [Jsoup](https://jsoup.org/) for parsing.

```
// capture rendered page
WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
HtmlPage myPage = webClient.getPage("https://pokevision.com");

// convert to jsoup dom
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(myPage.asXml());

// extract data using jsoup selectors
Elements images = doc.select("img[src~=(?i)\\.(png|jpe?g|gif)]");
for (Element image : images) {
    System.out.println("src : " + image.attr("src"));
}

// clean up resources
webClient.close();
```