# JSoup CSS / DOM questions

Tags: java, css, dom, jsoup

[image]

1.
(From:https://www.virustotal.com/en/file/7b6b268cbca9d421aabba5f08533d3dcaba50e0f7887b07ef2bd66bf218b35ff/analysis/)

I want to get the text in the picture, in Google Developer Tools I would do that (I basically went into another childnode of the span to find the md5 in DevTools but in Jsoup it seems different and only returns the "md5" text)

`document.getElementById("additional-info-content").childNodes[1].children[1].childNodes[1].innerHTML`

I cant manage to get it using JSoup dom/selector. 
(If it's possible to give both of these examples)

---

2.

How do I specify a child in CSS in Jsoup?
For example, I right click on the span class field above the blue marked line in the picture, and click "Copy Selector":

```
#file-details > div:nth-child(2) > div:nth-child(1) > span
```

It gives me file-details as first div, even thought its not the only file-details in the document, but okay, lets say it should be like that(?):

```
#additional-info-content > div:file-details > div:nth-child(2) > div:nth-child(1) > span
```

How do I manage to translate it into a working JSoup CSS script with the child? (If possible then DOM example aswell)

---

3.

Is there a good insight on how to look and how to find the right path when looking for a specific value/node?

What I do now is basically open Developer Tools, then click on a unique div class name, and I check the properties window inside the DevTools for the child nodes, and keep digging with the child nodes till I find the right path...(Like I copied in the first question)

Is there a better way to look at this?

I mean, using the DevTools console is so simple, just writing
.children[1].childnodes[3].children[1] while looking at the properties and seeing the correct attribute that I need, but I know it's not the right way I guess?

Comment: Hello. Please [ask one question per post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/222735/can-i-ask-only-one-question-per-post). Also since jsoup is Java library you would probably get better responses with `java` tag instead of `javascript`.

Comment: Also answers for your first and second questions are probably here https://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/selector-syntax and in Element/Elements documentation (maybe also with Node if you are interested in handling text nodes separately).

Comment: So should I edit the question and make 2 more threads?
And I've looked at it but I still don't manage to get the right values of what I need :(.

Comment: Yes, try to focus on one thing at a time in posts. If you have specific problem with code it is always good idea to include your code attempts ([SSCCE](http://sscce.org) / [MCVE]) in post.

Comment: Well, I think this time ill keep it all together since it's all relevant to each other and the picture, I'll edit and add the website where the code is from so people are able to look at it beside the picture.
Ill do that next time, thanks a-lot though Pshemo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1)

```
    // connect to url and retrieve source code as document
    Document doc = Jsoup
            .connect(url)
            .userAgent("Mozilla/5.0")
            .referrer("http://www.google.com")
            .get();

    String md5= doc

            // use CSS selector to grab only enums which contain md5
            .select("div#file-details.extra-info > div.enum-container > div.enum:contains(md5)")

            // use the first element in the result set
            .first()

            // use only its text node and ignore the text node of the span
            .ownText();
```

---

2)  There are lots of ways to specify children.  You can use CSS selectors or some of the jsoup convenience methods.

If I want to extract the text `foo` from the following html:

```
<html>
 <body>
  <div> 
   <span><b>foo</b></span> 
   <span><b>bar</b></span>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Each of these will produce the same result:

```
    doc.select("div > span > b").last().ownText();

    doc.select("div > span > b").get(1).ownText();

    doc.select("div > span:last-child > b").text();

    doc.select("div > span:last-child").text();

    doc.select("div > span").last().text();

    doc.select("div > span").get(1).text();

    doc.select("div > span:last-child > b").first().ownText();

    doc.select("span > b").last().text();
```

Deciding which way to go really depends on the HTML structure of the document you are parsing.  See [CSS Selectors](http://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/selector-syntax) for more examples.

---

3) Examine the source code, not the code rendered in the browser.  Jsoup does not invoke JavaScript.  If the DOM of your page is changed onLoad, then you need to render the page before parsing it.  Here is an example of how to do this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38572859/1176178

Comment: I'm still unable to get the code I pointed to in the picture :(.
Is it because, the text itself is outside a span/element?

In the google dev tools i'm able to go to the MD5 childs and get it, but in JSoup I can't manage to do it :(.

Comment: @ShlomiBazel I edited my response to question 1.  It looks like the site you are scraping is limited to certain user agents.  I set it to Mozilla and was able to pull down the md5 hash.

Comment: Thanks dude, appreciate it.