# Jsoup: Pull addresses from exhibitors list and store in excel file

Tags: jsoup

**Background:** I am trying to simply a task at my workplace. I am currently a senior working on my B.S. in Computer Science at the UT Dallas so I have a solid computer science foundation. However I have no experience with Jsoup.

**Task:** Pull addresses from exhibitor list (https://ahm19.mapyourshow.com/7_0/alphalist.cfm?alpha=*) and store each address individually in one excel file.

**Thoughts:** My guess at the steps needed to automate this task would be something like this:

1. Interact with search bar to choose State/Providence, then choose given State, then search
2. For each company in the exhibitors list I need to select it and then pull company name and address, and store in excel file.

Is this relatively easy? Is this possible? Any help is appreciated. I've linked some screenshots below.

[List and search eg.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ziMl9.png)

[Company profile eg.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3PWGc.png)

Comment: You won't be able to scrap that page using Jsoup. Jsoup works by examining the raw HTML file as retrieved from the server (same as when you 'view source' in the browser. However, the page you're describing appears to render the data on the fly by modifying the DOM. So you need to either render the page with something like HtmlUnit and parse it from there.

Comment: Here is an example of how to do that: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38572859/1176178